# Unable to resolve javax.annotation.Priority dependency issue in maven project

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, java-10

I'm starting a Jersey, Springboot project with swagger integration but I'm having issues resolving the **javax.annotation.Priority** dependency. I came across
[this link](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Dependencies-On-Java-EE-Modules) and I have experimented with adding the suggested modules and also added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but so far nothing resolves this issue for me.
I'm working on MacOS and compiling in Java 10.

Comment: Not enough information here but check that you don't have `--add-modules java.se.ee` or `--add-modules java.xml.ws.annotation`. If so then these will prevent the Java EE version of javax.annotation from being used.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add anything. Jersey will pull in the transitive. Does it work with Java 8 or 9?

Comment: @AlanBateman Thanks. I had to remove all java.xml.ws* modules for the project to run. If you could make this an answer so I could accept.